# Get total amount per mode using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
 <?php
    $ctr = 0;
    while($ctr <= 10){
    ?>
    <td><input required type='text' name='amount[<?echo $ctr; ?>]' class='amount'></td>
    <td><input required type='text' name='mode[<?echo $ctr; ?>]' value='Cash'></td>
    <?php
    $ctr++;
    }
    ?>
    Total Amount: <span class="total_amount">0.00</span>
    Total Cash : <span class="total_cash">0.00</span>
    Total Check: <span class="total_check">0.00</span>

$(document).on('blur','.amount',function () {
    var total = 0;
    var total_cash = 0;
    var total_check = 0;

    $('.amount').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    $('.total_amount').html(total);
});
```

Using the code above, I can get the total amount of the number I encode in the input amount fields.  How can I get the total per mode, cash(default) and check (user can change mode to check)?

Comment: You could use a data element on the amount to link it to the mode. data-mode-input='mode[0]' and then use an attribute selector in the input to determine if it's cash or check. ie "input[name='mode[0]']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sure, that next input width `mode` always corresponds, you can use JQuery.next. So it is necessary to check the value of each parameter to NaN.

```
$(document).on('blur','.amount',function () {
    var total = 0;
    var total_cash = 0;
    var total_check = 0;
    var val, mode;
    $('.amount').each(function () {
        val = parseFloat($(this).val());
        val = val ? val : 0;
        total += val;
        mode = $(this).next().val();
        switch(mode) {
            case "Check" : total_check += val; break;
            case "Cash"  : total_cash  += val; break;                
        } 
    });

    $('.total_amount').html(total);
    $('.total_cash').html(total_cash);
    $('.total_check').html(total_check);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ag0a78jd/

Comment: hi sir, actually every input is in <td> and i think next is not working with this scenario. sorry my bad for not putting the td in the question

Answer (score 1):

The following only works if your indexes are consistent (eg. every `amount[x]` has a `mode[x]`):

```
var total = {};

$('.amount').each(function(idx)
    {
        var mode = $('[name="mode['+idx+']"');

        if (!total[mode.val()])
            total[mode.val()] = 0;

        total[mode.val()] += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
);
console.log(total);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r3cm40s/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to get the index of the current element in the set of "amount" elements.

```
var index = $( ".amount" ).index( this );
```

Get the corresponding Cash/Check element value with the index you got just above

```
var mode_value = $("input[name='mode["+index+"]']").val();
```

Then check that value and store the value in the right variable

```
if (mode_value == "Cash")
total_cash = total_cash + $(this).val();

if (mode_value == "Check")
total_check = total_check + $(this).val();
```

The whole code must be inside the blur event.